# Tables vs Div vs Spans

Tags: css, html-table

I have always heard that it is better to avoid using `<table>` in HTML.

However, I encountered a situation in which a table would make my life easier when building a page that shows multiple products and their characteristics.

Should I try to hack it so that I do not need a table, or should I just go with a table?

Comment: Use tables for tabular data. For layout - learn CSS.

Comment: In this case, it is tabular data, so why should you avoid a table?

Comment: @BillyMathews I think it was the way it was asked...

Comment: @BillyMathews I _think_ I fixed it up a bit...

Comment: No need to have more than 1 answer, if your answer is the same(use tables for tabular data) just upvote the existing one. Dear bounty hunters, Thank you

Comment: How is that not constructive? This question have a constructive answer and its not specific. Come on...

Answer (score 5):

No, you should not avoid the TABLE concept. Learn/Use it to display tabular data, not web layouts.

Learn about those elements from the W3C.

1. [Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)
2. [Div](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div)
3. [Span](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span)

Answer (score 0):

I use tables constantly in web apps - they provide a perfectly good and predictable way to display results in any browser.

Comment: Yes, results of **tabular** data ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Tables are for tabular data (like an excel sheet, etc)

Use CSS for times when the data is **not** tabular.

Tables are **not** dead, you just need to use them right :-)